# Fault code decoding

Tags: obd

I tried getting mode 03 (fault code) for Volkswagen Polo and Toyota Innova. I am unable to find how to decode it. Can someone please help me decode it (the method to decode the hex response)

Volvo:  7E8 10 0C 43 05 00 73 26 1A 
        7E8 21 01 03 01 04 01 13 AA (This AA byte at the end is causing the problem to understand how to decode)

Innova: 7E8 06 43 02 06 07 12 64

Answer (score 2):

Mode 6

This mode gives the results of self-diagnostics done on systems not subject to constant surveillance.

AA      Misfire data cylinder 9
The Volvo-a lot those codes are exhaust gas sensors etc

Mode 3

This mode shows the stored diagnostic trouble codes. These fault codes are standard for all makes of vehicle and are divided into 4 categories:

```
P0xxx: for standard faults linked to the powertrain (engine and transmission)
C0xxx: for standard faults on the chassis
B0xxx: for standard faults on the body
U0xxx: for standard faults on the communications network
```